# Sharekit - Facebook configuration

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I am trying to integrate sharekit in an ios app. Everything works properly but I have problem with Facebook. What I'have done so far :

1. created an app on Facebook (no extra configuration on Facebook, like native etc..)
2. edited SHKConfig.h and added
   `#define SHKFacebookAppID @"MyFacebookAppID"`
3. in my app.plist added the url scheme : fb+appID
   Now When I try to share something on Facebook, the Facebook app on the device is opened, showing the message : You are logging into this app as "facebookUsername", when I click ok
   I'm redirected to my app but nothing happen, no sharing action.
   I am missing something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem is illustrated here [sharekit installation guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) step 6

Comment: @Danish it's not. He can't receive bounty on his own answer ;)

Comment: @Martin oh so who get the bounty

Comment: @Danish nobody. It will vanish

Answer (score 1):

**Things You have to do for Integrate Sharekit With your Application..(Recommended)**

1) Actually You dont need to set URL scheme in .plist file for Sharekit. It's only for facebook API users..

2) Check out,Did you **fill api key and secret key in SHKConfig.h** file like this below

```
#define SHKFacebookKey              @"YOUR_API_KEY"
#define SHKFacebookSecret           @"YOUR_APP_SECRET_KEY"
```

3) Verify Did you **"import SHK.h"** file..

4) You have to include **"MessageUI,SystemConfiguration and Security frameworks"**.

5) You **dont need** to do this `#define SHKFacebookAppID @"MyFacebookAppID"`

6) **Invoke sharekit actionsheet** as given in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [SHKConfig.h](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/blob/master/Classes/ShareKit/SHKConfig.h) file seems to indicate that you don't include a literal "+" in your URL scheme. Check the last line of this quote:

```
// Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/
// SHKFacebookAppID is the Application ID provided by Facebook
// SHKFacebookLocalAppID is used if you need to differentiate between several iOS apps running against a single Facebook app. Leave it blank unless you are sure of what you are doing. 
// The CFBundleURLSchemes in your App-Info.plist should be "fb" + the concatenation of these two IDs.
// Example: 
//    SHKFacebookAppID = 555
//    SHKFacebookLocalAppID = funk
// 
//    Your CFBundleURLSchemes entry: fb555funk
```

Comment: Actually I do not include the + in my url scheme, anyway I managed to solve this.